# add space between isotope item rows (fitRows)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-isotope

i tried so much but i can't solve it. Need to add more space between the rows in isotope (metafizzy)

this is the init-script

```
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    sortAscending: true
    }
});
```

for the css i'm using bootstrap without any custom edits for the items in isotope

Here the site: http://gabrielw.de/steamlib/?profile=xunocore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just give your items a padding on the bottom so that they have padding.  Rather than try and force isotope to pad them you can just include them in the item's CSS

```
.isotope .isotope-item {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: this helped me as of 2015! woop woop! @zuriel